# Printing into a txt file

Tags: python

I want to print in a txt file only then a specific event, that is my code:

```
txt = tutto()
file = open("psw.txt", "w")
file.write(str(txt))
file.close()
```

`tutto()` is a `def` ( `def tutto():` ). In `tutto` there are a lot of `print` commands. How can I redirect all these print commands only after `tutto()` is started?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, your question is not clear. If the `tutto` function has many `print` commands, they will not be executed until `tutto` is begun by being called. Please explain further. It would help if you show us a minimal `tutto` function that demonstrates your problem and tell us the desired output and the actual output and how they differ. Also, are you able to edit the `tutto` function?

Comment: If you're using Python 3.4+, the [`contextlib.redirect_stdout()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout) function would allow you to do what (I think) you want. Note the examples. If you're using an earlier version, it would be fairly simple to write your own version of something like — let us know if you need help doing that when you [edit] your question to clarify what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

`print` accepts a file parameter that designates where the output will be printed to. By default, the location is sys.stdout (which is normally your terminal). You can modify the definition of tutto so that it uses a special print function. `functools.partial` is used to help you create your own print function so that you don't have to type `print("...", file = fout)` everywhere. Once tutto ends, `print` will return to its normal behavior since you are only changing its definition in the scope of `tutto`.

```py
import sys
from functools import partial

def tutto(fout = sys.stdout):
    print = partial(__builtins__.print, file = fout)
    print("Here are all")
    print("my print statements")
    print("They will automatically show up in")
    print("The file designated by fout...")
    return

with open("Sample.txt", "w") as f:
    print("Calling tutto")
    tutto(f)
    print("Tutto is finished, and I'll appear in your terminal.")
```

Outputs:

```
Terminal:
Calling tutto
Tutto is finished, and I'll appear in your terminal.
```

```
Sample.txt:
Here are all
my print statements
They will automatically show up in
The file designated by fout...
```

Comment: How did you interpret the question, which is unclear? Did you interpret it that the questioner wants all the printing in the `tutto` function to end up in the file? What if the function also returns a value, as seems the case in the sample code--is that to go in the file also?

Comment: I interpreted it like they want anything `print`ed in tutto to appear in a file instead of the terminal. If they also want to write the return value, then they could change the call to `tutto` to be `f.write(tutto(f))` which will write the return value after `tutto` has finished executing.

Comment: I have a def (tutto) with inside a lot of print command, in the terminal this def start only after a button pression make with tkinter, but the txt file don't wait the button pression to write so in the txt is blank

Comment: @pingu-lo If you're still having problems, I suggest you make a new question and define your requirements more clearly. A minimal example using tkinter, your button, and the behavior you expect vs. the behavior you are getting.